# What's the name of this five petaled flowering shrub?

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

I saw it next to a parking lot recently, and took this picture. The plant isn't very tall.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any closer photos? It looks like a wigelia to me, but it is hard to tell from the photo.

Comment: what part of the world was the picture taken in?

Comment: I think I can see a flower with five petals - was wondering if its Paraheba catarractae, but if there are 5 petals, its not that, they have 4 petals. One of the Abelias, otherwise?

Comment: Looks like Rhaphiolepis...but the lavender flowers are different...please send close ups of leaves, berries? flowers...